# Change content of multiple files

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have uploading 3700 + HTML Files to my server. I have made a custom website. In whole website there is one similar div with same id in all files, now i need to change content  of that div.
For Example, in 3700 + HTML files there is div some thing like that  :

```
<div id="leftbar">
  Same Content
</div>
```

Now I need to make it :

```
 <div id="leftbar">
     Update Same Content
 </div>
```

I have not included any JS file in whole website. I didn't use any PHP tag in whole website.
Updating one by one to all 3700 +  Files will take MUCH time ! I need to save my that time.
Any suggestion will be highly appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You have got a couple of options but the best one i think will be just using the replace function that your IDE gives you. if its with netbeans you can use `CTRL+SHIFT+H` – and replace the string with a new string.

Comment: I have no open file in My Editor.

Comment: I cant understand what you mean with "i have no open file"
you are not using an IDE?

Answer (score 0):

You can include this script into your documents, or add the 2 lines to whichever JS file you include already :

```
<script>    
  var leftbar = document.getElementbyId('leftbar');
  leftbar.innerHTML = 'Update '+leftbar.innerHTML
</script>
```

Or you can use sed in your terminal to replace your string in all html files.

```
sed -i 's/oldstring/newstring/g' *.html
```

Comment: I know that, I mentioned in question that i didn't include any JS file in those 3700 + files, so you mean that i should paste this line of code to 3700 + files, isn't it ?

Comment: are you running Unix?